# Invalid keyword argument on new model entry

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class mark(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=35)
    url=models.URLField(max_length=200)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
```

and then I use a form to save some data to the db. My code inside the view that saves the data is:

```
new_mark= mark(url=request.POST['url'],
                           title=request.POST['title'],
                           user=request.user)
new_mark.save()
```

Of course I have all the data validation, login required validation, etc. 
When I run this it throws me an unexpected

```
'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

on the`user=request.user)` line. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the whole traceback and make sure your view has no function named "mark" etc (You probably also want to change `mark` to `Mark` to follow Python and Django style guides.) test via `print type(mark)` before the `"new_mark = …"` line.

Also I am not 100% sure if a ManyToMany field allows settings data like that, eg try:

```
new_mark= mark(url=request.POST['url'],
                       title=request.POST['title'])
new_mark.user.add(request.user)
new_mark.save()
```

And since it's an m2m field you probably want to rename the field to users.

Comment: Yes that fixed it. I was not aware of the difference when inserting ManyToMany Fields